# What is Factories in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, factory

What is Factory in Magento2? Why use this. I want to know more details about Factory. When we can use Factory.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html#step-5-factory-object

Answer (score 2):

As you know in **OOP**, a factory method will be used to instantiate an object. In Magento 2, the Magento 2 Factory Object do the same thing. **Factories** are service classes that instantiate non-injectable classes, that is, models that represent a database entity. They create a layer of abstraction between the ObjectManager and business code.

The **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager** is the class responsible for instantiating objects in the Magento application. Magento prohibits depending on and directly using the **ObjectManager** in your code.

Factories are an exception to this rule because they require the ObjectManager to instantiate specific models.

Unless you require specific behavior for your factory classes, you do not need to explicitly define them because they are an automatically generated class type. **When you reference a factory in a class constructor, Magento’s object manager generates the factory class if it does not exist.**

`Factories follow the naming convention <class-type>Factory where <class-type> is the name of the class the factory instantiates`.

*For example* the automatically generated **Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory** class is a factory that instantiates the class **Magento\Cms\Model\Block.**

The Factory class name is the name of Model class and append with the Factory word. So for our example, we will have TopicFactory class. You must not create this class. Magento will create it for you. Whenever Magento’s object manager encounters a class name that ends in the word ‘Factory’, it will automatically generate the Factory class in the var/generation folder if the class does not already exist. You will see the factory class in

```
var/generation/<vendor_name>/<module_name>/Model/ClassFactory.php
```

To instantiate a model object we will use automatic constructor dependency injection to inject a factory object, then use factory object to 
instantiate the model object.

You can get the singleton instance of a factory for a specific model using dependency injection And Factories are smart enough to resolve dependencies and allow you to get the correct instance of an interface as defined in your module’s di.xml.

[For more click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)